# Hide items in ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I would like to implement a filter in flutter and change dynamically the ListView based on the items that comply with the filters. I have a list of peoples (represented by the class People with attribute AGE in it). For instance I would like to show people with age < 18, but WITHOUTH REMOVING the items from the list generating the list view, just HIDE the items from the ListView that do not comply with the filter.

Comment: It can be done by map or conditional state inside list, can you include your code-snippet and what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: what you should hide is from your Logic side, not your UI side, try to filter the list from your state management and display the filtered result

Answer (score 0):

Using [Visibility Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)  from flutter sdk we can hide/show as we need

Answer (score -1):

You only need to put a condition for rendering the list, and show the person only if he/she is < 18. you can do something like this in your listview:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (person.age < 18) 
      return Text(person.age);
    return SizedBox();
  },
)
```

Comment: This nonetheless shall be visible in the ListView. If you have used border decorations in you ListView, you will see an empty spot but the borders will be visible. Instead of "return Text('');" I want to say to not build at all this item, jump it and move to the next one.

Comment: Not returning anything in the UI is not possible, because of the flutter's null safety you have to return something in case the condition is not met. So if you want to not render it at all you should do something as Jim Chiu suggested, filter it in the logic.